# How to change script installation location in python

Tags: python, windows

I installed python in a directory but when i install a script, it installs in %appdata%/python folder (must be the default directory for installing scripts).

I tried using:
"pip config set global.target C:\Program Files\Pypy3.12.2\Scripts"
I got this:
"ERROR: Got unexpected number of arguments, expected 2. (example: "pip config set [name] [value]")"

Sorry if it a dumb question, im a beginner

Comment: the issue may be that you need to quote your path so it's not interpreted as several statements due to the literal space in it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote your path with double quotes:

```
pip config set global.target "C:\Program Files\Pypy3.12.2\Scripts"
```

Double quotes are needed because the path contains whitespace.